# How to sort data in text format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have data in Excel and my data contain below format:

Year  |  WeekNo
2024  |  Week 1
2024  |  Week 2
2024  |  Week 3
.
.
.
2024 |  Week 11
2024 |  Week 12
2024 |  Week 13
.
.
so on.

When I applied filter on **WeekNo** column the data looks like below format in Filter:
Week 1
Week 11
Week 12
Week 13
.
.
.
Week 19
Week 2
Week 20
Week 21
.
.
Week 29
Week 3
Week 31
Week 32
.
.
so on.

I want to see data in sequencial format in filter like :
Week 1
Week 2
Week 3
.
.
Week 11
Week 12
Week 13
So on.

May I know, what shall I do to see the data in filter like this, please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Do not enter "Week 1" but 1 in the week column and then use a custom number format: `"Week " 0`

Comment: if the header itself describe about what data it is holding you can skip writing it in all below rows, in above example column header describes week no so can only write 1,2 ..11 and so on in the column those number generally read as week no only.

Comment: Thanks for your update , I will do the same

Comment: Another option would be using 2 digits, so `Week 01, Week 02, ....Week 19, Week 20, Week 21....` would get sorted correctly because of the leading zeros